# Unary operator behaviour

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num,i=0;
num=-++i+ ++-i;
printf("%d",num);
return 0;
}
```

I am getting compilation error for above example.
I understood like, unary (+) operator returns const value. but below example is not satisfying that condition.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int x,i=1;
x=~-i;
printf("%d",x);
getchar ();
return 0;
}
```

Here I am getting '0' as answer.

Can anyone explain me, what exactly '+' operator does in c.

Comment: Before that what are you trying to achieve with your code? `x=~-i;`?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that applying `++` twice in the same expression without a sequence point is undefined behavior, how would you expect the second `++` of `num=-++i+ ++-i;` to work?

Comment: For your question "Can anyone explain me, what exactly '+' operator does in c.", a `+` operator is used as it should be, to add numbers. `++` is used to increment the value by 1. For example `i++` increases the value of `i` by 1.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior

Comment: @ArunA.S To confuse things a bit, there are actually two + operators in C, the binary one and the unary one. The unary plus is mildly useful though, mainly included to make the language consistent, as there is also the far more useful unary minus.

Comment: @Lundin, I have pointed out both of these in my comment "a `+` operator is used as it should be, to add numbers.", that is binary `+` and " `++` is used to increment the value by 1", that is unary.

Comment: @ArunA.S I was speaking of binary `+` and unary `+`. Anyway, it was just a side note, not important :)

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for notifying, you meant that I didn't say about unary `+`.( that is `+1`,`+2`, etc... the one used to specify that it is positive )